# How to to load environment variable on System level and not on User level in Log4Net

Tags: c#, windows, environment-variables, log4net

I've struggled in this for a couple of hours with no avail.

I need to use an environment variable called **`TMP`** or **`TEMP`**, which hold the Windows Temp folder to which I want to log. Usually it's `C:\Windows\Temp` (of course this value might change from one system to another, that's why I need the variable value).

The problem is there are two values for each of those keys:

[image]

I use the following XML to instruct Log4Net (under C#) to load the temp folder (pasted the relevant part):

```
  <appender name="SomeFileAppender" type="log4net.Appender.RollingFileAppender">
  <file value="${TMP}\Logs\SomeLogFileName.log" />
  <appendToFile value="true" />
```

When I ran my program, it writes the log into the users temp folder:
`C:\Users\myuser\AppData\Local\Temp\Logs`

The question is how do I force Log4Net to take the environment variable of TMP/TEMP from system level and not user level ?

Comment: You can't. That dialog is presenting the variables as if there was a separate hierarchy for programs to access -- there is not. The system variables are taken, then the user variables are added/updated, then *that* is passed as the whole environment block for any application. The registry stores these variables separately, but applications don't access them separately. That's not specific to log4net. Is there any reason you don't simply specify your own global variable that is *not* overridden at the user level? Regular users aren't even able to  access `C:\Windows\Temp` by default.

Comment: If you absolutely, positively need the value defined at the system level for this environment variable, you'll need to pluck it from the registry (`HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Control\Session Manager\Environment`) and configure the appender at runtime. But I don't see any great advantage over this compared to simply putting the path in the `.config`. It's no great burden for integrators to have to change the configuration of your application, if they've already gone so far as to change the default location of temporary files.

Comment: Thanks @JeroenMostert. I used WINDIR variable as a workaround. Calling the registry seemed to hacky.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If your application is being run by a specific user, you would typically want to write only to user-specific directories. C:\Windows\TEMP is a directory shared among all the users of your PC. If you really want to write to that, typically you would want to run your application as a System user.

(This is just the typical scenario; granted that there may be individual circumstances where you want a specific user to write to a system-wide directory.)

Now if you run as SYSTEM, you would pick up the System-level definitions of TMP/TEMP into your environment.

Comment: I'll check that up... maybe that's indeed solved by itself. Thanks !

Answer (score 0):

If indeed `@JeroenMostert` is right, and it ain't possible (without turning to the registry), I used the `WINDIR` environment variable (which value is **C:\Windows**) as a work around as I'll show next.

Still, if someone comes up with a better answer I'll be glad.

```
  <appender name="SomeFileAppender" type="log4net.Appender.RollingFileAppender">
  <file value="${WINDIR}\temp\Logs\SomeLogFileName.log" />
  <appendToFile value="true" />
```